# Trouble logging in with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication

I am trying to create a login page for the first time with ajax, but it isn't properly working. I have a login HTML that lets the user input the username and password with a submit button that calls the javascript script when it is clicked. When the proper password displayed below is entered I would like for it to go to the home html page, but nothing happens when I type in the password seen below. I could attach the HTML code if it would be helpful, but I think that it is a problem with this code as I get an error of: POST http://localhost:5000/login 404 (NOT FOUND). How would I properly change the code to make sure that I would be able to get to the home page?

```
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        $.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            url:'http://localhost:5000/login',
            data: {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
            if(data.username == "user" && data.password =="pass"){
                window.location.href = "home.html";
                }
            else{
                alert("Invalid Credentials");
            }
                }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to get the correct url to post the data to. It all depends on how you have your server set up.

Comment: You aren't preventing the default submit process, so not clear if the 404 is from that or from the ajax. Start by using https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ or `return false` from event handler

Comment: Currently, I am just running the files locally. This login script is linked to a login HTML page. Would I have to set up a local HTTP server to be able to have this login page?

Comment: `localhost:5000` implies you are running a local server on port 5000. Is that not the case? Last comment is confusing

Comment: I am not running a local server, instead, I am using Flask to run a python script and am just opening the HTML files in chrome. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider something like the following.

```
function login(u, p) {
  var r = false;
  $.post("http://localhost:5000/login", {
    username: u,
    password: p
  }, function(data) {
    if (data.username == "user" && data.password == "pass") {
      r = true;
    }
  });
  return r;
}

$("#submit").click(function(e) {
  $(this).closest("form").trigger("submit");
}

$("#submit").closest("form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var username = $("#username").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();
  var result = login(username, password);
  if (result) {
    window.location.href = "./home.html";
  } else {
    console.log("Login Error");
  }
});
```

Considering that you may be using a login form, you may want to bind to the `submit` callback instead. You can put the Ajax call into it's own function to make it a little easier to use. If there is a successful login, you can perform the redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have actually tried another approach in which I just put in the javascript form in the HTML file. The problem with the code now is that it never is able to get the proper username and passcode. It always says I got the wrong credentials. I added the code up top.